# Create Dropdown List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

So I need to implement a few drop down lists for a web app. I linked my web app to my database using the entity model, made all my classes and everything. How to create a drop down list that is populated with items from a column in a table in my db?

Here is the class from one of the models I am trying to use:

```
Partial Public Class gasrevperyear
   Public Property ID As Integer
   Public Property year As Integer
   Public Property amount As Integer
End Class
```

Here is the code in the view for the page I want to implement the drop down on

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of gasrevperyear)
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Gasoline Revenue Per Year"
End Code

<h2>Gasoline Revenue Per Year</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.year)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.amount)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@For Each item In Model
@<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.year)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.amount)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", New With {.id = item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", New With {.id = item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
Next

</table>

@Html.DropDownListFor(Model.gasrevperyear, gasrevperyear.year, "1990")
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please show code you have (part of view with rendering of dropdown and basic sample of model).

Comment: Side note: avoid extra text like "searched a lot", "new here", "give guidance"... instead post concrete details and generally show your effort in solving it. Unfortunately something like "searched 100 hours" is not considered effort to solve.

Comment: You need a lot more details. This is not enough to help you.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I added the code for the class from my model, and the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to create the drop down list function. I usually do this with a LINQ query, but you could also do it manually:

**With Query:**

```
Public Function gasrevperyearDD() As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
  Dim List As New List(Of SelectListItem)
  List.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Text = "Select An Item", .Value = 0})
  Dim valQ = From v In table
             Where v IsNot Nothing
             Select v
  For Each i In valQ
    List.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Text = i.SomeString, .Value = i.ID})
  Next
  gasrevperyearDD = List
End Function
```

**Without Query**

```
Public Function gasrevperyearDD() As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)
  Dim List As New List(Of SelectListItem)
  List.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Text = "Select An Item", .Value = 0})
  List.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Text = "SomeString", .Value = 1})
  List.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Text = "SomeString", .Value = 2})
  gasrevperyearDD = List
End Function
```

Then in your controller defining the view you need to create a ViewData Element calling the function `ViewData("DropDown") = gasrevperyearDD`

Finally in your view you simple call on the ViewData element to populate the dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.gasrevperyear, DirectCast(ViewData("gasrevperyearDD"), IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)))
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m.gasrevperyear, ViewData("gasrevperyearDD"))
```

Comment: What if that column is integer? Can I still put it into the text for the select list item?

Comment: @user3055062 yes the `.Text` element of select list can be either a string or an integer; if you get an error you would simply say `.Text = Value.tostring`

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: " error BC36604: Late binding operations cannot be converted to an expression tree"

Comment: @user3055062 I don't believe the two are related. Have you run debug to see where exactly the error occurs?